# format jquery variable with html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I am jquery to copy values from existing asp.net label to another asp.net texbox.
The challenge I am having is formatting the text been copied as bold using standard html tags

```
$subject = $("[id$=lblrequestsubject]").html(); 
$topic = $("[id$=lblrequesttopic]").html();
$("#<%=txtdescription.ClientID%>").html("\n\n\n\n"+"Subject: "+$subject +"\n"+"\n"+"Topic: "+$topic.bold()); //set value
```

so what I need to do is format the $topic and $subject variables as bold.

Kindly help.
Thanks

Comment: ASP:textbox (input type='text') does not support html formatting

Comment: Are you trying to display the text as bold in some other div or element?

Comment: @source.rar $("#<%=txtdescription.ClientID%>") suggest that is over a textbox control

Comment: Any other option for this

Answer (score 0):

First: <%=txtdescription.ClientID%> Must be a div, or some other element that allows nesting of other tags inside of it. It will not work with textarea element. Assuming this is a , the following code snip will work:

Second: usage of .html() implies the contents of your labels is more than just text, use .text() to get only the text values.

```
$subject = $("[id$=lblrequestsubject]").text();

$topic = $("[id$=lblrequesttopic]").text();

$("#<%=txtdescription.ClientID%>").html("\n\n\n\n"+"Subject: "+$subject +"\n"+"\n"+"Topic: <span style='font-weight:bold;'>"+$topic+"</span>"); //set value
```